# Ошибка развертывания maven deploy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

Пытаюсь собрать maven проект. На стадии maven deploy получаю ошибку:

```
 Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project test_mongo: Execution default-deploy of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy failed: For input string: "port" ->
```

Пробовала в pom.xml добавить описание maven deploy plagin, но в итоге стало только хуже

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <groupId>ru.habrahabr</groupId>
    <artifactId>test_mongo</artifactId>

    <version>0.0.1</version>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
            <url>http://domain:port/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <url>http://domain:port/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <version.jdk>1.8</version.jdk>
        <version.spring>5.3.23</version.spring>
        <version.spring.mongodb>3.4.3</version.spring.mongodb>
        <version.jackson>1.9.13</version.jackson>
        <tomcat.version>9.0.68</tomcat.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring.mongodb}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jackson}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- TEST -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${version.jdk}</source>
                    <target>${version.jdk}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Причем при выполнении mvn install проходит все успешно и формируется war файл в локальном репозитории .m2. Если можно запустить его, то я не понимаю как это можно сделать непосредственно через  tomcat (положила архив в папку webapss, а также в эту папку отправляла сформированную папку, в которой хранится war файл, но все безуспешно)

Comment: `domain:port` тут все указано правильно? и какой командой запускаете, с каким id репозитория?

Comment: последняя выполняемая команда mvn install, domain:port, как и id репозитория по факту нигде и не указывала